# Can't get value of tag using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, data-mining

my code:

```py
value_list = soup.findAll("div", attrs ={"class":"value"})
```

`value_list[0]` has :

```
< div class="value" data-v-d3544a4c="" >
                            Movie< !-- -- >< /div >
```

when I try to get the tag value with `value_list[0].string` I get a `None` returned.

how can I get the value otherwise?

Comment: Hi @Itan Mallul Welcome to SO! did you tried with `.text` method? and if possible can you share URL

Comment: What data are you trying to get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** *In new code use `find_all()` instead of old `findAll()` syntax - your html looks not valid*

```
value_list = soup.find_all("div", attrs ={"class":"value"})
```

To get the text of the tag use `.text` or `get_text()`:

```
value_list[0].get_text(strip=True)
```

#### Example

```
html = '''
<div class="value" data-v-d3544a4c="" >
                            Movie< !-- -- ></div >
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
value_list = soup.findAll("div", attrs={"class":"value"})
value_list[0].get_text(strip=True)
```

#### Output:

```
Movie< !-- -- >
```

Comment: I tried using find_all() instead but it didn't fix it.
when using get_text(), I get \n\t\t\tMovie\n\t\t\t

Comment: both `find_all()` / `findAll()`will work the same way - You can strip the string with `.get_text(strip=True)`

Comment: it worked! thanks for the help! if I had the contribution I'd upvote you